# Looking For A Way To Draw Part Of An Image Using Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am using [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) with Python3 and looking to draw a PNG image but only part of the image based on a value. For example if I have a range between [0, 100] and have a value of 50. I would like to draw 50% of the image.

Currently I use kivy.graphics.Rectangle to draw a rectangle with the PNG image as the source attribute. Then I update the size of the rectangle based on the value coming in (50 in this case).

This solution just stretches and compresses the image, but always draws the whole image. I would prefer to keep the size static and have the % of the image actually shown be the dynamic component.

I have been looking for a way to do this but haven't found any leads. This is complicated a little more by the fact that I have a background so I can't just put a white rectangle over the drawn image and change the size of that to hide the fully drawn image behind it.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change the rectangle's `tex_coords` property to adjust what part of the image is displayed.

Comment: I will read into `tex_coords` I haven't worked with that feature before, thanks!

Comment: Another possibility is to use [StencilView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.stencilview.html).

Comment: Thank you @JohnAnderson I was able to use StencilView to do just this!

Answer (score 0):

I used code similar to this in order to limit the displayed image:

```
canvas:
    # Draw our stencil
    StencilPush
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.x, root.center_y - self.height / 1.5
        size: self.update, 1000
    StencilUse

    # Now we want to draw our image and then crop it
    Rectangle:
        size: self.width, self.height + self.height / 2
        pos: self.x, root.center_y - self.height / 1.5
        source: self.source
    StencilUnUse

    # Redraw our stencil
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.x, root.center_y - self.height / 1.5
        size: self.update, 10000 # Note height was not a concern here
    StencilPop
```